# Custom drop down field on front end user profile not saving

Tags: php, wordpress

I've created a drop down selection on a front end user profile which includes all custom post type posts.

On selecting it doesn't actually save the selection, it just reverts back to the first option.

Where am I going wrong?

This is the code I have in my functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_custom_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_custom_profile_fields' );
function save_custom_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'teampage', $_POST['teampage'], get_user_meta( $user_id, 'teampage', true ) );
}

add_action( 'personal_options', 'add_profile_options');
function add_profile_options( $profileuser ) {
    $greeting = get_user_meta($profileuser->ID, 'teampage', true);
    ?><tr>
    <th scope="row">Member of which Health Board?</th>
    <td>
        <select name="teampage" id="teampage" >
            <?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'board', 
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            )); ?>
            <?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>  
                <option id="Yes" <?php selected( $profileuser->teampage, 'Yes' ); ?>><?php echo the_title(); ?></option> 
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr><?php
}
```

I'm using [this tutorial](http://codesleepshred.com/how-to-add-options-to-user-profiles-using-personal_options/).

Comment: Is this working from the back-end? How are you displaying the user profile edit screen on the front-end?

Comment: @NikolaIvanovNikolov It's on the front-end via the Theme My Login plugin which links through to the back-end. I just can't get it to update both ends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what your problem is. It's a couple of little mistakes that you made. Here is the working code:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_custom_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_custom_profile_fields' );
function save_custom_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'teampage', $_POST['teampage'], get_user_meta( $user_id, 'teampage', true ) );
}

add_action( 'personal_options', 'add_profile_options');
function add_profile_options( $profileuser ) {
    $greeting = get_user_meta($profileuser->ID, 'teampage', true);
    ?><tr>
    <th scope="row">Member of which Health Board?</th>
    <td>
        <select name="teampage" id="teampage" >
            <?php $portfolioloop = new WP_Query( array( 
                'post_type' => 'board', 
                'post_status' => 'publish'
            ));
            global $post; ?>
            <?php while ( $portfolioloop->have_posts() ) : $portfolioloop->the_post(); ?>  
                <option <?php selected( $profileuser->teampage, $post->ID ); ?> value="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></option> 
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </select>
    </td>
    </tr><?php
}
```

You forgot to add the `value` attribute to each `option`.

Also you shouldn't check against the same value for all options(you used `selected( $profileuser->teampage, 'Yes' );`, which essentially checks whether the value of `$profileuser->teampage` is `Yes`). Instead we assign the post ID to each option and we check against that.